# Is there a way to drop LOCAL variables that are no longer needed in VST?

Tags: verifiable-c

When working through longer functions when using verifiable-C, it is often the case that `LOCAL` variables are no longer needed after a certain point.  In particular, the C-light translated code often adds many `LOCAL` variables that are only used briefly.

Is there a tactic or lemma in VST that I can use to discard a `LOCAL` variable when I know that it will no longer be needed.  This can help reduce the clutter in the `LOCAL` context.  I'm also hoping that it will be able to speed up VST as well as I find that it gets slower as my `LOCAL` context gets bigger and bigger (though the slowdown might be unrelated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try the suggested `deadvars!` tactic, but when the remaining statements is large, the `deadvars!` tactic turn out to be quite slow.

However, I did find the `drop_LOCALs` tactic in the manual, and while using it might be a little less robust, it worked well and improved the memory use of checking my script (a bit less than I had hoped, but it was a definite improvement).

Answer (score 0):

Try the deadvars!  tactic.  (Look it up in VC.pdf manual, but really, just say    deadvars!.

Comment: By the way, there is serious hope that, when you truly have lots of LOCAL variables, a not-too-distant-future release of VST can get much faster, by using the techniques described here: https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/VST/pull/712